# Change "Tom Smith" into "TSmith"

Tags: powershell

The title says it all. My question to all is how can I do this better?

```
$a = "Tom Smith" ; $e = $a.substring(0,1)
$ee = ($a).split(" "); $y = $e + $ee[1]; $y
TSmith
```

Any guidance on improvements would be great.

Comment: Since it's hard-coded, why don't you just eliminate the first two lines?

Comment: It's not a whole lot of code but as long as it works as intended we can have a look over at the Code Review site. If you do post it there, make sure you delete it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Given that the code works (even as simple as it is) this is probably more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than this site.

Comment: I get a feeling that this is example code, i.e. stripped down just to be an example. In that case, it would be off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: We agreed in Code Review chat that this was very close to example code and would likely get closed. Please leave it here.

Comment: Cross-posted to Code Review (where it has been closed): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86330/extracting-first-initial-and-last-name

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I would use this as what you have does work on its own but if you were looking for improvement then this would do more error prevention. Say if the name contained more that one space.

```powershell
Function Get-UserName{
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FullName
    )

    # Check if there is at least a space (not in the first position) in the string passed. 
    If($FullName.IndexOf(" ") -gt 1){
        # Use the format operator to make the output a little more readable. 
        # $fullname[0] grabs the first character
        # $FullName.Split(" ",2)[1] -replace "\s" is the last name and removes any spaces. 
        # Make it all lowercase (optional for you). 
        ("{0}{1}" -f $fullname[0],$FullName.Split(" ",2)[1] -replace "\s").ToLower()
    } Else {
        Write-Error "'$FullName' does not appear to have a first and last name"
    }
}
```

Now it accepts pipeline input and reacts if there is no space in a proper position. There is still a margin for error here but its better than nothing.

So you could use it like in the following examples.

```powershell
Get-UserName -FullName "Matt Vasquez"
Get-UserName "BumbleBee Joe"
"Skimpy McMar Janeson" | Get-UserName
```

Which would net the following output:

```powershell
mvasquez
bjoe
smcmarjaneson
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to improve this.

#### Naming

Your naming is of no use to help understand what your script does. Look how much easier this reads with proper, useful names:

```
$inputName = "Tom Smith" ; $firstLetter = $inputName.substring(0,1)
$lastName = ($inputName).split(" "); $result = $firstLetter + $lastName[1]; $resultString
TSmith
```

#### It's doesn't do much

Obviously the scope of it is very limited as presented. Literally all the code does is take `Tom Smith` and make it `TSmith`. Make it take an input of some kind to make it more flexible! Then once you get that working, bring it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell?sort=newest&pageSize=50) to get your whole script improved!